# Callable function from yaml

Tags: python, yaml, typeerror

I'm trying to implement a CommandHandler that reads a command dictionary from a .yml and should call the method based on the user input

commands.yml:

```
'help': {
    'message': 'message',
    'help': 'help-message',
    'action': help_command
},
'news': {
    'message': 'news-message',
    'help': 'help-message',
    'action': news_command
}
```

CommandHandler.py:

```
def handle_command(self, command, parameters, message):
    self.commands.get(command).get('action')(parameters, message)
```

I get a `TypeError: 'str' is not callable`. With.json its the same error.
Saving it as commands.py and importing it gets me a `NameError: name 'help_command' is not defined`.

However, if I just throw the dict into the code directly it works fine.
Is there any solution besides defining the dict in the code directly?

Comment: Are we talking about JSON or YAML?

Comment: A Python `dict` can store a reference to a function, because that function is also a Python object. You can't serialize  a function and store it in a YAML file.

Comment: @chepner OP could pickle the dict, though...

Comment: @timgeb pickle does the trick! that was exactly what I was looking for!
And I was talking about YAML but tried it with JSON before aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`help_command` in YAML loads as a string. YAML does not know about symbols defined in the Python file where it is loaded and anyway won't map strings to symbols.

You can, of course, do

```py
def handle_command(self, command, parameters, message):
    eval(self.commands.get(command).get('action'))(parameters, message)
```

Be aware of `eval`'s security implications though. You should never run this if the YAML comes from an untrusted source, it can do anything.